# Como mudar o nome do processo de um programa em C\C++ (Lib Windows)

Tags: c, c++, windows

Estou criando um programa de utilitário para o windows mais não consigo mudar o nome que aparece no gerenciador de tarefas, já tentei `SetConsoleTitle("atwconnect");` mas mudou só o nome da janela mas não o nome do processo do gerenciador de tarefas.

Alguém sabe como mudar o nome do processo e adicionar uma descrição do programa no processo também ?

Comment: Se estiver a usar visual studio, acho que a solução passa por criar um ficheiro .rc (resource). Por exemplo, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022449/how-to-change-an-executables-properties-windows

Comment: Existe algum tutorial de como escrever um arquivo .rc ?

Answer (score -2):

muda o argv[0] onde fica o nome do processo, ex: argv[0] << "nome";

Comment: Apesar do baixo nível técnico é uma tentativa de resposta. O que cabe a negativação e não a exclusão.